# How do compare data from table 1 with Table 2 MS SQL server and display the result?

Tags: php, python, sql, sql-server

Consider an example where i have two table named `Table A` and `Table B`, I have a `column name - Site ID and Site Name` in `Table A`

Data in Table B is entered through a python script, there's a column name Site ID in it. So whenever data is entered in Table B, it should compare it with Table A and enter the Site Name from Table A to Table B respective of their Site ID.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: You should create a trigger if you want to make this feature will be easier for you

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output data

Comment: updated the question, kindly help with the solution.